# How to do shell escape in Texniccenter?

Tags: shell-escape

I heard that PStricks pictures can be compiled separately using the command shell escape.
What should I do in order to implement it in my document? I cannot find any tutorial explaining the procedure to follow.
If this issue had already been treated, please provide me the corresponding link.

Answer (score 4):

You have to go to `Build>Define Output Profile`. Select `Latex to PDF` and add to the list of `Command line arguments to pass to the compiler`:

- -shell-escape if you're under TeX Live
- --enable-write18 if you're under MiKTeX.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Texniccenter cannot compile some pictures. Nevertheless when I type the command: pdflatex -shell - escape FileName in the command, I get my file compiled. However the output  looks bad if there is too much data. Figures are overlapping one another. I guess it is because of the subfloat environement.
Can you please tell me how you declare the tikz and externalize environment in your preambel?

Comment: It would be hard to say: I hardly ever use `tikz` except for some commutative diagrams with `tikz-cd` and I don't have to externalise them, as it is natively understood by pdflatex. As for `pstricks`, `pst-plot` and the like,, it is required to  load in the  preamble `auto-pst-pdf`, or (simpler) add `pdf` to the document class options.