# Horizontally align x-axis of a curve figure and a contour figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have two subfigures generated by Tikz, one is a curve plot and the other is a contour plot. The x-axis actually are the same so I want to align them horizontally.

I gave a minimal working example below. Some features are necessary: no y label for (b), colorbar for (b) is put on the right side.

[image]

I am new to tikz. I am not sure if this is really a tikz thing, which means I can align them when generating tikz figure and simply import as a graphic file using \includegraphics, 
or a subfigure thing, which means I do nothing in generating tikz figure, but use some resizing or shifting commands in subfigure environment to align them.

I am not which one of these two ways are better.

Any idea on that ? Thanks !

The code for MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfigure[a]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width = 8.7 cm,
                height = 6cm,
                scale only axis,
                xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
                ymin = -1e-3, ymax = 1e-3,
                xlabel = {Foo},
                ylabel = {Bar 1},
                ]
                \addplot[red, samples = 100] {1e-3*x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \subfigure[b]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width = 8.7 cm,
                height = 6 cm,
                scale only axis,
                view = {0}{90}, 
                xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
                ymin = 0, ymax =1,
                xlabel = {Foo},
                point meta min = 0, point meta max =2.5,
                colormap/jet,
                colorbar,
                colorbar style = {ytick = {0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5}},
                ]

                \addplot3[surf,shader = interp] {exp(x)};           

            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \caption{bla bla}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've attempted to use so far? If so, please add it.

Comment: I can't put the source file here since the data file is too large... I will try to work out a simple example and put it below.

Comment: Of course you don't need to provide the full (real) data set here. You can simply add "dummy data" or don't add data to the plots at all.

Comment: By the way: Welcome to TeX.SX!  And just in case you shouldn't know it: Have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks, @StefanPinnow, I edit the original post and give a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed your question now in that way, that you need subfigures. Hopefully this is not a requirement, because then you can do the alignment in *one* `tikzpicture` environment. Please note that I have changed your code a bit to easiliy present a kind of MWE which is in most cases the `standalone` documentclass. Because that does not provide a `figure` environment I have commented these parts of the code.

For a description, how the code works, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        positioning,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=newest,
        %
        % put all the stuff that is the same for the plots together here
        % in a style
        bla bla style/.style={
            scale only axis,
            width=8.7cm,
            height=6cm,
            xmin=-1,
            xmax=1,
            ymin=-1e-3,
            ymax=1e-3,
            view={0}{90},
            xlabel={Foo},
        },
    }
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        % use the style here
            bla bla style,
            %
        % list all stuff that is different in the plot here
            ymin=-1e-3,
            ymax=1e-3,
            ylabel={Bar 1},
            %
        % give the plot a name
            name=top plot,
        ]
            \addplot[red,samples=100] {1e-3*x};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
        % use the style here
            bla bla style,
            %
            %%% place this axis relatively to the above plot
            % use as anchor of this plot the «north west corner of the plot ...
            anchor=north west,
            % ... and align the anchor to the anchor «below south west» of
            % the above plot ...
            at={(top plot.below south west)},
            % ... and shift it down a bit
            yshift=-2mm,
            %
        % list all stuff that is different in the plot here
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            point meta min=0,
            point meta max=2.5,
            colormap/viridis,
            colorbar,
            %
        % give the plot a name
            name=below plot,
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] {exp(x)};
        \end{axis}

    % in case you really need the labels I suggest to place them by hand
    % and explain the labels in the (main) caption. But I would consider to
    % just refer them as «top» and «bottom» in the (main) caption
        \node (label a) at ([xshift=-2ex]top plot.left of north west) {a)};
        \node at (below plot.left of north west -| label a) {b)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \caption{bla bla}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

---

### Edit

As promised here is a solution with the `external` library of `tikz`/`pgfplots` which "automatically" externalizes pictures. This requires the `shell-escape` feature to be on. If you have never heard about it, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222632/how-to-do-shell-escape-in-texniccenter) is explained how to activate it in TeXnicCenter.

Here in short how my solution works. (Only the new parts compared to the above solution are described.) To visualize the `bounding box` I fill it with the `BB style`, which adds a yellow color at the end of the picture on the `background` layer. This layer I have declared in advance and have set it below the `main` layer. Next comes the `\tikzexternalize` command which activates the image externaliziation. The added keys hopefully are      self-explanatory. Last I have declared the new command `\UseAsBB` to set the bounding box of the plots. But to be sure that there are no parts from the plot already larger than declared in `\UseAsBB` I put the `axis` environment in the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment. After that I use the `\UseAsBB` command to set the `bounding box` explicitly.

More details you will find in the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.external,
    }
    % declare layer `background' and set it before the `main layer'
    % the layer is used to set and visualize the bounding box
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \tikzset{
        % define a style to apply to each `tikzpicture' to visualize the
        % bounding box by setting a fill color in the background of the
        % bounding box
        % (comment everything in the style if you are sure the bounding box
        % fits everything)
        BB style/.style={
            execute at end picture={
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                    \path [
                        fill=yellow,
                    ]
                        (current bounding box.south west)
                        rectangle
                        (current bounding box.north east);
                \end{pgfonlayer}
            },
        },
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.13,
        %
        % put all the stuff that is the same for the plots together here
        % in a style
        bla bla style/.style={
            scale only axis,
            width=8.7cm,
            height=6cm,
            xmin=-1,
            xmax=1,
            ymin=-1e-3,
            ymax=1e-3,
            view={0}{90},
            xlabel={Foo},
            % don't calculate the bounding box
            overlay,
        },
    }
    % `shell-escape' feature needs to be enabled so
    % image externalization works "automatically"
    \tikzexternalize[
        % only externalize pictures which are explicitly named
        only named=true,
        % set a path here, to where the pictures and plots should be externalized
        prefix=Pics/pgf-export/,
%        % uncomment me to force image externalization
%        % (in case you didn't change anything in the `tikzpicture' environments
%        % itself which would lead to an externalization, too
%        force remake=true,
    ]
    % define a command to set the bounding box
    \newcommand*{\UseAsBB}{
        \useasboundingbox
            % adjust the `shift' values to the bounding box
            % does include all stuff
            ([xshift=-15mm] current axis.below south west)
            rectangle
            ([shift={(18mm,7mm)}] current axis.north east);
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
    \subfloat[bla][Bla]{%
        % set a name of the picture
        \tikzsetnextfilename{curve_plot}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            BB style,
        ]
            \begin{axis}[
                % use the style here
                    bla bla style,
                    %
                % list all stuff that is different in the plot here
                    ymin=-1e-3,
                    ymax=1e-3,
                    ylabel={Bar 1},
            ]
                \addplot[red, samples = 100] {1e-3*x};
            \end{axis}
            % use defined command to set the bounding box
            \UseAsBB
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
        \qquad
    \subfloat[blub][Blub]{%
        % set a name of the picture
        \tikzsetnextfilename{contour_plot}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            BB style,
        ]
            \begin{axis}[
                % use the style here
                    bla bla style,
                    %
                % list all stuff that is different in the plot here
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=1,
                    point meta min=0,
                    point meta max=2.5,
                    colormap/viridis,
                    colorbar,
            ]
                \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp] {exp(x)};
            \end{axis}
            % use defined command to set the bounding box
            \UseAsBB
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{This is the main caption.}
        \label{fig:cont}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above (edited) code]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I didn't make myself clear. But I really need to put these figures in a journal paper, so could you work out a way to use the article documentclass and figure environment ?

Comment: @zljt3216, perhaps I didn't make myself clear as well in my answer. I used the `standalone` documentclass here, so you get "exactly" the same output as shown in the figure. If I would have used for example the `article` class, there would have been a lot of whitespace, which is not relevant to the question. So there is no problem to exchange to documentclass and then use the figure environment.  Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Stefan,  I tried and it definitely worked. The only drawback is that you have to put figure label a) and b) manually because you put them in the same "tikzpicture" environment. I searched around and get another way out of this using the \useasboundingbox command.

Comment: @zljt3216, after presenting your answer it seems really to be a necessity to use subfigures. But there is a much more elegant way then for "exporting" the plots. I'll show this here tomorrow morning, because today I'll not be on a computer any more having LaTeX installed. The keyword here is the `tikz`/`pgfplots` library `external`. See you tomorrow.

Comment: Stefan (seems I cannot @ you), it takes me some time to understand your answer. But one more question is that your new solution is embedded in the article class. This works for simple cases, like the MWE. But in fact, my contour plot used in my paper is really large with lots of data, so it is impossible to put the contour plot in the article and compile them together. Instead, I would have to first compile these figures independently and output as an pdf file and import them in the article. I  am not sure if your new solution can be modified to that way ?

Comment: @zljt3216, when you write a comment to a question/answer, the author is _always_ informed; so there is no need to @ me.

Comment: @zljt3216, I assume you get an "out of memory" error, when you state, that you cannot compile "them together". A memory error has nothing to do with the used `documentclass`. To avoid these errors, have a look at "[Large datafile for pgfplots table gives out of memory](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272729)" and "[increasing hard coded memory limits of latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277108)", which hopefully help you.

Comment: @zljt3216, nontheless I always have an extra TEX file with the full preamble containing _only_ the pictures and plots created with `tikz` and `pgfplots`. With that I am able to comment all the pics and plots I am currently not working on and can very fast compile the pics/plots. When I have finished editing them I can also simply externalize them (as shown in my above answer). Then I only need to compile the remaining pics/plots that contain references from the whole/original TEX file.

Comment: @zljt3216, last I wanted to note: If you think that my response has answered your (above) question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @zljt3216, if you have another problem or a sub-problem, you are free to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

A "not elegant" way to do this is using *\useasboundingbox* command. In this way, I have to manually tune the size of boundingbox and add some margin. The alignment is not perfect, but enough for me in this case.

The code for MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}        
% I use standalone class, since I figure out I can output these two figures in a single pdf file and import them using \includegraphics[Page= x]{filename}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width = 8.7 cm,
            height = 6cm,
            scale only axis,
            xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
            ymin = -1e-3, ymax = 1e-3,
            xlabel = {Foo},
            ylabel = {Bar 1},
            ]
            \addplot[red, samples = 100] {1e-3*x};

        \end{axis}
        \useasboundingbox (0cm,0cm) rectangle (10.5 cm, 0 cm);      % manually add some margin on the right side
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            yshift=-2mm,
            width = 8.7 cm,
            height = 6 cm,
            scale only axis,
            view = {0}{90}, 
            xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
            ymin = 0, ymax =1,
            xlabel = {Foo},
            point meta min = 0, point meta max =2.5,
            colormap/jet,
            colorbar,
            colorbar style = {ytick = {0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5}},
            ]

            \addplot3[surf,shader = interp] {exp(x)};                       
        \end{axis}
        \useasboundingbox (-1.5cm,0cm) rectangle (0 cm, 0 cm);      % manually add some margin on the left side
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]